# composer network install instruction giving Erorr: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, voting-system, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to install a network using Hyperledger Composer but I am getting some errors. I used the following instruction

`composer network install --archiveFile vote-network@1.0.0.bna --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1`

and its giving me this error...

```
✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
Command failed
```

My fabric is running, I have all the containers running in my docker. Some answers suggested that proxy was the issue and I tried to disable the proxy with different instructions, but I don't know it is disabled or it is actually the issue or not. When I run the command...

```
curl http://www.google.com
```

I am getting response in html which means that proxy is still running (as per another suggestion).

Please help in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

what OS are you running? If uBuntu, try older version 16.04 LTS. I had a similar message and went down to 16.04 and it works.